# Convert Nested JSON Object to CSV using Dataweave

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft

I'm trying to do salesforce bulk api v2 (upsert) and i have few lookups that i need to send in request. my json payload looks like below:

```
[{
"Sold_To_Account__r:"{
    "type":"Account",
    "SAP_Customer_External_Id__c":"1004680001"
},
"Related_Partner_Account__r": {
    "type": "Account",
    "SAP_Customer_External_Id__c":"1004680001"
}
```

}]

Is it possible to convert to CSV and do bulk insert to salesforce ?

Comment: How do you need the json to look like?

Comment: What is the expected CSV output? Otherwise it is not possible to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

Following the Salesforce documentation for [Relationship Fields for Custom Objects](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_bulk_v2.meta/api_bulk_v2/datafiles_csv_rel_field_header_row.htm), I understand that you will need to create a CSV with the following format:

```
Sold_To_Account__r.SAP_Customer_External_Id__c,Related_Partner_Account__r.SAP_Customer_External_Id__c
1004680001,1004680001
```

To get that you can use a script like this one:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/csv
---
payload map
{
    "Sold_To_Account__r.SAP_Customer_External_Id__c": $.Sold_To_Account__r.SAP_Customer_External_Id__c,
    "Related_Partner_Account__r.SAP_Customer_External_Id__c": $.Related_Partner_Account__r.SAP_Customer_External_Id__c
}
```

I'm not sure if this is enough or you will need to send also some unique key like the 'Name'. In the past, I remember creating a string concatenating all the IDs for the relationship as the 'Name'.

Comment: on OrderItem object , ProductId is a field which is of lookup(product). If i need to send this field what is the way ?

Comment: @Learner did you try adding a column with 'Product2Id.ExternalId' to OrderItem?